# install boost 1.51 package on centos 7

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, boost

I'm trying to compile a program which requires boost 1.51, but the only available boost package via yum on my system is boost 1.53. I would prefer to install boost using the system's package manager, rather than from source. How might I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Why are you trying to downgrade boost?

Comment: I'm basically following some instructions to compile an old, proprietary, unmaintained application. I'm being told that it compiles with boost 1.51, but not with more recent versions. Maybe (prboably?) there's a better solution, but my C++ knowledge verges on non-existent.

Comment: It ought to work fine. If it doesn't, it should be a trivial fix. Borrow a C++ developer from somewhere for an hour, like perhaps [so].

Comment: That's probably a good idea. Does that also mean that there isn't an easy way to downgrade boost with yum?

Comment: No, because you'll break everything else on the system that uses boost.